Material-ui Datagrid is unstable keep refreshing
Below is the code I am using to get data from an api and binding it to the materi ui datagrid. Version I am using is  "@mui/x-data-grid": "^7.18.0", the highlighted portion at the bottom is what keeps flickering and keeps growing. Any pointers would help . thank you.
the code is pretty simple and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

const [adUsers, setADUsers] = useState<IADUser[]>([]);

const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState<boolean | undefined>(undefined);

const [showGrid, setShowGrid] = useState<boolean | undefined>(undefined);

 const onSearchHandle = (e: any) => {
    if (validate()) {
        setShowLoader(true);
        let response: IADUser[];
        userStore.getAdUsers(searchText).then((data) => {
            setADUsers(data);
        });

        setShowLoader(false);
    } else {
        console.log("Validation failed");
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (showLoader == false) {
        setShowGrid(true);
    }
}, [showLoader]);

 const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
        field: "mail",
        headerName: "Email",
        width: 450,
        // renderCell: (params) => (
        //     //<a className="hyperink" href="#" onClick={() => userClickHandler(params.row.mail, params.row.firstName, params.row.surname)}>
        //         {params.row.mail}
        //     //</a>
        // ),
    },
    {
        field: "firstName",
        headerName: "Firstname",
        width: 450,
    },
    {
        field: "surname",
        headerName: "Surname",
        width: 450,
    },
];

 <div className="col table-responsive p-2">
                            {showGrid && (
                                <DataGrid
                                    getRowId={(row: IADUser) => row.rowId as number}
                                    rows={adUsers}
                                    columns={columns}
                                    initialState={{
                                        pagination: {
                                            paginationModel: {
                                                pageSize: 10,
                                            },
                                        },
                                    }}
                                    pageSizeOptions={[10]}
                                    disableRowSelectionOnClick
                                />
                            )}
                            {showLoader && <Spinner />}


The issue you're experiencing with flickering and growth in the highlighted portion might be due to how the loader state is handled. Try these couple of changes:

Ensuring setShowLoader(false) is called after data is fetched:
const onSearchHandle = async (e: any) => {
 if (validate()) {
  setShowLoader(true);

  try {
     const data = await userStore.getAdUsers(searchText);
     setADUsers(data);
   } catch (error) {
     console.error("Failed to fetch AD users:", error);
   } finally {
     setShowLoader(false);
   }
 } else {
     console.log("Validation failed");
  }
};





The useEffect to set showGrid to true whenever showLoader becomes false works, but you may simplify it by toggling showGrid based directly on the loading state:
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!showLoader) {
      setShowGrid(adUsers.length > 0);
    }
  }, [showLoader, adUsers]);




I tried the above code but same issue exists.
